# How every block in matplotlib (imshow) should be made clickable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I have 2 matrices and I'm displaying them through `imshow` using matplotlib. I have embedded the matplotlib in a small GUI using PyQt5. Each block represents each value in the matrix respectively. I want these block to be clickable. The reason to make it clickable is that Whenever each block will be clicked, another matplotlib plot would pop up. Before proceeding to this stage, I want the blocks to be clickable. How can I achieve this ?? I have tried several methods from internet but no luck.

GUI picture

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, \
QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QInputDialog, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout,     QStackedLayout, QFormLayout
from  PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import time
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as     NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


j=0
figure = plt.figure()

H = np.array([[100, 2, 39, 190], [402, 55, 369, 1023], [300, 700, 8, 412], [170, 530, 330, 1]])
Z = np.array([[3, 290, 600, 480], [1011, 230, 830, 0], [152, 750, 5, 919], [340, 7, 543, 812]])


class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        # a figure instance to plot on
        self.figure = plt.figure()

        # this is the Canvas Widget that displays the `figure`
        # it takes the `figure` instance as a parameter to __init__
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        # this is the Navigation widget
        # it takes the Canvas widget and a parent
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

        # Just some button connected to `plot` method
        self.button = QPushButton('Plot')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.loop)
        self.button.setDefault(False)

        self.stop = QPushButton("Stop")
        self.stop.clicked.connect(self.loopStop)
        self.stop.setDefault(False)

        self.exit = QPushButton('Exit')
        self.exit.clicked.connect(self.closeIt)
        self.exit.setDefault(True)

        self.leBtn = QPushButton('Enter Vmin')
        self.leBtn.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonOK_clicked)
        self.leBtn.setDefault(False)

        self.lineedit = QLineEdit(self)
        validator = QtGui.QIntValidator()
        self.lineedit.setValidator(validator)
        self.lineedit.returnPressed.connect(self.leBtn.click)

        self.leBtn1 = QPushButton('Enter Vmax')
        self.leBtn1.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonOK_clicked1)
        self.leBtn1.setDefault(False)

        self.lineedit1 = QLineEdit(self)
        validator = QtGui.QIntValidator()
        self.lineedit1.setValidator(validator)
        self.lineedit1.returnPressed.connect(self.leBtn1.click)


        # set the layout
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.stop)
        layout.addWidget(self.exit)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        layout.addWidget(self.leBtn)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit1)
        layout.addWidget(self.leBtn1)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def on_pushButtonOK_clicked(self):
        self.vmin = int(self.lineedit.text())

    def on_pushButtonOK_clicked1(self):
        self.vmax=int(self.lineedit1.text())


    def plot(self):
        global j
        if j == 0:
            j += 1
            rows, cols = H.shape

            im = plt.imshow(H, interpolation='nearest', cmap='bwr', vmin=self.vmin, vmax=self.vmax, extent=[0, cols, 0, rows])
            v = np.linspace(0, 1023, 15, endpoint=True)
            ax1 = self.figure.add_axes([0.85, 0.093, 0.04, 0.8])
            cax = self.figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
            self.figure.colorbar(im, cax=ax1, orientation='vertical', ticks=v)
            self.canvas.draw()

        elif j == 1:
            j -= 1
            rows, cols = H.shape

            im = plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest', cmap='Spectral', vmin=self.vmin, vmax=self.vmax,
                        extent=[0, cols, 0, rows])
            v = np.linspace(0, 1023, 15, endpoint=True)
            ax1 = self.figure.add_axes([0.85, 0.093, 0.04, 0.8])
            cax = self.figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
            self.figure.colorbar(im, cax=ax1, orientation='vertical', ticks=v)
            self.canvas.draw()

    def loop(self):
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setSingleShot(False)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.plot)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def loopStop(self):
        self.timer.stop()

    def closeIt(self):
        self.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Window()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to catch the click event you must do it through the canvas and the `mpl_connect('button_press_event', {some_callback})` method:

```
class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        [...]
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_button_press_event)
        [...]

    def on_button_press_event(self, event):
        print(event)
```

**Example:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, \
QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QInputDialog, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout,     QStackedLayout, QFormLayout
from  PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import time
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as     NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


j=0
figure = plt.figure()

H = np.array([[100, 2, 39, 190], [402, 55, 369, 1023], [300, 700, 8, 412], [170, 530, 330, 1]])
Z = np.array([[3, 290, 600, 480], [1011, 230, 830, 0], [152, 750, 5, 919], [340, 7, 543, 812]])


class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        # a figure instance to plot on
        self.figure = plt.figure()

        # this is the Canvas Widget that displays the `figure`
        # it takes the `figure` instance as a parameter to __init_
        self.im = None
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_button_press_event)

        # this is the Navigation widget
        # it takes the Canvas widget and a parent
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.plot)
        self.timer.setInterval(5000)

        # Just some button connected to `plot` method
        self.button = QPushButton('Plot')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.timer.start)
        self.button.setDefault(False)

        self.stop = QPushButton("Stop")
        self.stop.clicked.connect(self.timer.stop)
        self.stop.setDefault(False)

        self.exit = QPushButton('Exit')
        self.exit.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.exit.setDefault(True)

        self.leBtn = QPushButton('Enter Vmin')
        self.leBtn.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonOK_clicked)
        self.leBtn.setDefault(False)

        self.lineedit = QLineEdit(self)
        validator = QtGui.QIntValidator()
        self.lineedit.setValidator(validator)
        self.lineedit.returnPressed.connect(self.leBtn.click)

        self.leBtn1 = QPushButton('Enter Vmax')
        self.leBtn1.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonOK_clicked1)
        self.leBtn1.setDefault(False)

        self.lineedit1 = QLineEdit(self)
        validator = QtGui.QIntValidator()
        self.lineedit1.setValidator(validator)
        self.lineedit1.returnPressed.connect(self.leBtn1.click)


        # set the layout
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.stop)
        layout.addWidget(self.exit)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        layout.addWidget(self.leBtn)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit1)
        layout.addWidget(self.leBtn1)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.lb = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.lb.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.ToolTip)

    def on_pushButtonOK_clicked(self):
        self.vmin = int(self.lineedit.text())

    def on_pushButtonOK_clicked1(self):
        self.vmax=int(self.lineedit1.text())


    def plot(self):
        global j
        if j == 0:
            j += 1
            rows, cols = H.shape

            self.im = plt.imshow(H, interpolation='nearest', cmap='bwr', vmin=self.vmin, vmax=self.vmax, extent=[0, cols, 0, rows])
            v = np.linspace(0, 1023, 15, endpoint=True)
            ax1 = self.figure.add_axes([0.85, 0.093, 0.04, 0.8])
            cax = self.figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
            self.figure.colorbar(self.im, cax=ax1, orientation='vertical', ticks=v)
            self.canvas.draw()

        elif j == 1:
            j -= 1
            rows, cols = H.shape

            self.im = plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest', cmap='Spectral', vmin=self.vmin, vmax=self.vmax,
                        extent=[0, cols, 0, rows])
            v = np.linspace(0, 1023, 15, endpoint=True)
            ax1 = self.figure.add_axes([0.85, 0.093, 0.04, 0.8])
            cax = self.figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
            self.figure.colorbar(self.im, cax=ax1, orientation='vertical', ticks=v)
            self.canvas.draw()

    def on_button_press_event(self, event):
        print('button={}, x={}, y={}, xdata={}, ydata={}'
            .format(event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata))
        if self.im:
            message = str(self.im.get_cursor_data(event))
            delay = 1000
            w = self.lb.fontMetrics().width(message)
            self.lb.resize(w, self.lb.size().height())
            self.lb.setText(message)
            self.lb.move(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
            self.lb.show()
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(delay, self.lb.hide)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Window()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*Note: I changed the im variable to self.im to be able to access the value that is displayed in imshow*

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out. At least I got the idea how does this work. Now all I want is that when a specific block is clicked, a matplotlib window should pop up with some random data. I just need a little idea. Thanks again

Comment: If my answer will help you mark my answer as correct please

Comment: I updated the example by showing a popup with the contents of the cell

Comment: I really appreciate that. Thanks again. Marked as correct.

Comment: @HammadUllah Since you use squares you could take the xclick and yclick and determine which square was used using roundings. Like square (1,1) is the one with `roundup(xclick)==1 and roundup(yclick)==1`